How to show a binary tree like view in Graphviz for over 100+ nodes in a readable manner?
I have a graph.gv file which has around 125 nodes.
With more than 50+ nodes the view is looking very messy, so for 125 nodes it is even worse.
I want to see them in a binary tree like fashion as top-to-bottom with each node distinctly visible with their edges without any overlapping.
Is there any other style or mechanism I can adopt to write this below graph.gv to meet my requirement ?
digraph G {
    layout = dot
    rankdir = LR
    splines = true
    nodesep = 1.5
    ranksep = 1.5
    node [style=filled , shape=box, fontsize=40]
    edge [style = solid, color = black]
 geon [color=lightblue];
 pmp_wix [color=lightblue];
 jim_rxdx [color=lightblue];
 kfactor_usb_cps [color=lightblue];
 kfactor_usb_noc [color=lightblue];
 kfactor_usb_hrx [color=lightblue];
 kfactor_usb_mtx [color=lightblue];
 kfactor_usb_wcm [color=lightblue];
 kfactor_usb_cps_hrx_mtx_apr_rstsync [color=lightblue];
 kfactor_usb_fxp_apr_rstsync [color=lightblue];
 kfactor_usb_cps_rf_mems [color=lightblue];
 kfactor_usb_mtx_rf_mems [color=lightblue];
 kfactor_usb_wcm_rf_mems [color=lightblue];
 kfactor_usb_wcm_tcam_mems [color=lightblue];
 kfactor_usb_tcd [color=lightblue];
 kfactor_usb_tcd_sram_mems [color=lightblue];
 kfactor_usb_tcd_rf_mems [color=lightblue];
 kfactor_usb_tcd_tcam_mems [color=lightblue];
 cors_mangled_pre_ft [color=lightblue];
 kfactor_usb_top [color=lightblue];
 pre_pass [color=lightblue];
 rxdx_csv_beh_mem_pre_vizor [color=lightblue];
 vizor_insert_rxdx [color=lightblue];
 vizor_it [color=lightblue];
 vizor_filter [color=lightblue];
 stcdodegen [color=lightblue];
 create_gems [color=lightblue];
 bios_csv [color=lightblue];
 bios_csv_ff_mem [color=lightblue];
 bios_csv_asic_mem [color=lightblue];
 bios_csv_synth_mem [color=lightblue];
 assmble_fanout_rxdx [color=lightblue];
 localized_fanout_rxdx [color=lightblue];
 geostat_rxdx [color=lightblue];
 bios_cpp [color=lightblue];
 bios_rxdx_sunforce_rtl [color=lightblue];
 bios_rxdx_sunforce_uvm [color=lightblue];
 bios_rxdx_sunforce_crif [color=lightblue];
 bios_rxdx_sunforce_hdr [color=lightblue];
 bios_rxdx_sunforce_html [color=lightblue];
 bios_rxdx_sunforce_qchk [color=lightblue];
 bios_rxdx_sunforce_net2hdr [color=lightblue];
 bios_rxdx_sunforce_security [color=lightblue];
 rxdx_islimit_comp_ti [color=lightblue];
 rxdx_islimit_comp_drop [color=lightblue];
 pre_take_hi_zen_pre_vizor [color=lightblue];
 bios_pre_take_EM1 [color=lightblue];
 pre_take_hi_zen [color=lightblue];
 bios_pre_take_EM2 [color=lightblue];
 bios_pre_take_EM2_INITREG [color=lightblue];
 bios_pre_take_EM3 [color=lightblue];
 bios_pre_take_EM4 [color=lightblue];
 bios_pre_take_EM5 [color=lightblue];
 bios_pre_take_EM6 [color=lightblue];
 bios_pre_take_av_only [color=lightblue];
 bios_pre_take_rxdx_vizor [color=lightblue];
 bios_level0_EM1 [color=lightblue];
 bios_level0_EM3_short [color=lightblue];
 bios_level0_EM3 [color=lightblue];
 bios_level0_EM4 [color=lightblue];
 bios_level0_EM5_short [color=lightblue];
 bios_level0_EM5 [color=lightblue];
 bios_level0_EM6 [color=lightblue];
 bios_level0_av_only [color=lightblue];
 bios_level0_vizor [color=lightblue];
 bios_level0_dlw [color=lightblue];
 puni_run [color=lightblue];
 hicks_compile [color=lightblue];
 hrx_paradigm_gen_mtv_modulus [color=lightblue];
 hrx_paradigm_gen_mtv_sqe_cse [color=lightblue];
 hrx_paradigm_gen_mtv_sqe_par_ana0 [color=lightblue];
 hrx_paradigm_gen_mtv_sqe_par_ana1 [color=lightblue];
 hrx_paradigm_gen_mtv_sqe_par_non_ana_wcm [color=lightblue];
 hrx_paradigm_gen_mtv_sqe_lem_pmc [color=lightblue];
 hicks_strabstract [color=lightblue];
 hicks_run_top [color=lightblue];
 vespa_compile [color=lightblue];
 parx_us_par_non_ana_wcm [color=lightblue];
 parx_us_lem_pmc [color=lightblue];
 parx_us_par_ana0 [color=lightblue];
 parx_us_par_ana1 [color=lightblue];
 parx_us_cse [color=lightblue];
 parx_us_cps_hrx_mtx [color=lightblue];
 vespa_rxdx [color=lightblue];
 vespa_done [color=lightblue];
 gif_jkw_stratoplus_compile [color=lightblue];
 gif_jkw_stratoplus_run [color=lightblue];
 gix_vps_compile [color=lightblue];
 gix_vps_run [color=lightblue];
 mlcp_compile [color=yellow];
 mlcp_run [color=yellow];
 ui_hip [color=lightblue];
 ui_lib [color=lightblue];
 ui_elab [color=lightblue];
 ui_sdc [color=lightblue];
 ui_reg [color=lightblue];
 ui_fsdb_str [color=yellow];
 ui_profile_powers [color=lightblue];
 ui_gui [color=yellow];
 ui_power [color=lightblue];
 ui_report [color=lightblue];
 rxdx_jg_compile [color=lightblue];
 strnumer [color=lightblue];
 h2o2_rxdx [color=yellow];
 h2o2pkg_rxdx [color=lightblue];
 rxdx_sd_apt_compile [color=lightblue];
 rxdx_sd_apt_sam_autogen [color=lightblue];
 rxdx_check_lint_error_stage [color=lightblue];
 rxdx_sd_apt_run_top [color=lightblue];
 natofax_cps_hrx_mtx_sd_apt_sam_autogen [color=lightblue];
 natofax_cps_hrx_mtx_check_lint_error_stage [color=lightblue];
 natofax_cse_sd_apt_sam_autogen [color=lightblue];
 natofax_cse_check_lint_error_stage [color=lightblue];
 natofax_lem_pmc_sd_apt_sam_autogen [color=lightblue];
 natofax_lem_pmc_check_lint_error_stage [color=lightblue];
 natofax_lem_pmc_gui [color=lightblue];
 natofax_par_ana0_sd_apt_sam_autogen [color=lightblue];
 natofax_par_ana0_check_lint_error_stage [color=lightblue];
 natofax_par_non_ana_wcm_sd_apt_sam_autogen [color=lightblue];
 natofax_par_non_ana_wcm_check_lint_error_stage [color=lightblue];
 tcd_create_gems [color=lightblue];
 pre_sinus [color=lightblue];
 tcd_level0 [color=lightblue];
 zenf [color=lightblue];
    pmp_wix -> geon
    jim_rxdx -> pmp_wix bios_rxdx_sunforce_rtl bios_rxdx_sunforce_uvm
    kfactor_usb_cps -> jim_rxdx
    kfactor_usb_noc -> jim_rxdx
    kfactor_usb_hrx -> jim_rxdx
    kfactor_usb_mtx -> jim_rxdx
    kfactor_usb_wcm -> jim_rxdx
    kfactor_usb_cps_hrx_mtx_apr_rstsync -> jim_rxdx
    kfactor_usb_fxp_apr_rstsync -> jim_rxdx
    kfactor_usb_cps_rf_mems -> jim_rxdx
    kfactor_usb_mtx_rf_mems -> jim_rxdx
    kfactor_usb_wcm_rf_mems -> jim_rxdx
    kfactor_usb_wcm_tcam_mems -> jim_rxdx
    kfactor_usb_tcd -> jim_rxdx
    kfactor_usb_tcd_sram_mems -> jim_rxdx
    kfactor_usb_tcd_rf_mems -> jim_rxdx
    kfactor_usb_tcd_tcam_mems -> jim_rxdx
    cors_mangled_pre_ft -> kfactor_usb_cps kfactor_usb_noc kfactor_usb_hrx kfactor_usb_mtx kfactor_usb_wcm kfactor_usb_cps_hrx_mtx_apr_rstsync kfactor_usb_fxp_apr_rstsync kfactor_usb_cps_rf_mems kfactor_usb_mtx_rf_mems kfactor_usb_wcm_rf_mems kfactor_usb_wcm_tcam_mems kfactor_usb_tcd kfactor_usb_tcd_tcam_mems kfactor_usb_tcd_rf_mems kfactor_usb_tcd_sram_mems
    kfactor_usb_top -> cors_mangled_pre_ft
    pre_pass -> cors_mangled_pre_ft bios_rxdx_sunforce_rtl bios_rxdx_sunforce_uvm
    rxdx_csv_beh_mem_pre_vizor -> pre_pass bios_cpp
    vizor_insert_rxdx -> pre_pass rxdx_csv_beh_mem_pre_vizor bios_pre_take_EM1
    vizor_it -> vizor_insert_rxdx
    vizor_filter -> vizor_it
    stcdodegen -> vizor_filter
    create_gems -> cors_mangled_pre_ft vizor_filter
    bios_csv -> create_gems
    bios_csv_ff_mem -> create_gems
    bios_csv_asic_mem -> create_gems
    bios_csv_synth_mem -> create_gems
    assmble_fanout_rxdx -> create_gems
    localized_fanout_rxdx -> assmble_fanout_rxdx
    geostat_rxdx -> localized_fanout_rxdx
    bios_cpp -> geon
    bios_rxdx_sunforce_rtl -> geon
    bios_rxdx_sunforce_uvm -> geon
    bios_rxdx_sunforce_crif -> geon
    bios_rxdx_sunforce_hdr -> geon
    bios_rxdx_sunforce_html -> geon
    bios_rxdx_sunforce_qchk -> geon
    bios_rxdx_sunforce_net2hdr -> geon
    bios_rxdx_sunforce_security -> geon
    rxdx_islimit_comp_ti -> bios_rxdx_sunforce_security
    rxdx_islimit_comp_drop -> bios_rxdx_sunforce_security
    pre_take_hi_zen_pre_vizor -> bios_cpp pre_pass
    bios_pre_take_EM1 -> pre_take_hi_zen_pre_vizor
    pre_take_hi_zen -> bios_cpp create_gems
    bios_pre_take_EM2 -> create_gems bios_cpp pre_take_hi_zen
    bios_pre_take_EM2_INITREG -> create_gems bios_cpp pre_take_hi_zen
    bios_pre_take_EM3 -> create_gems bios_cpp pre_take_hi_zen
    bios_pre_take_EM4 -> create_gems bios_cpp geostat_rxdx pre_take_hi_zen
    bios_pre_take_EM5 -> create_gems bios_cpp pre_take_hi_zen
    bios_pre_take_EM6 -> create_gems bios_cpp pre_take_hi_zen
    bios_pre_take_av_only -> pre_pass bios_cpp pre_take_hi_zen_pre_vizor
    bios_pre_take_rxdx_vizor -> create_gems bios_cpp pre_take_hi_zen
    bios_level0_EM1 -> bios_pre_take_EM1
    bios_level0_EM3_short -> bios_pre_take_EM3
    bios_level0_EM3 -> bios_pre_take_EM3
    bios_level0_EM4 -> bios_pre_take_EM4
    bios_level0_EM5_short -> bios_pre_take_EM5
    bios_level0_EM5 -> bios_pre_take_EM5
    bios_level0_EM6 -> bios_pre_take_EM6
    bios_level0_av_only -> bios_pre_take_av_only
    bios_level0_vizor -> bios_pre_take_rxdx_vizor
    bios_level0_dlw -> bios_pre_take_EM3
    puni_run -> create_gems
    hicks_compile -> create_gems
    hrx_paradigm_gen_mtv_modulus -> hicks_compile
    hrx_paradigm_gen_mtv_sqe_cse -> hicks_compile
    hrx_paradigm_gen_mtv_sqe_par_ana0 -> hicks_compile
    hrx_paradigm_gen_mtv_sqe_par_ana1 -> hicks_compile
    hrx_paradigm_gen_mtv_sqe_par_non_ana_wcm -> hicks_compile
    hrx_paradigm_gen_mtv_sqe_lem_pmc -> hicks_compile
    hicks_strabstract -> hrx_paradigm_gen_mtv_modulus hrx_paradigm_gen_mtv_sqe_cse hrx_paradigm_gen_mtv_sqe_par_ana0 hrx_paradigm_gen_mtv_sqe_par_ana1 hrx_paradigm_gen_mtv_sqe_par_non_ana_wcm hrx_paradigm_gen_mtv_sqe_lem_pmc
    hicks_run_top -> hicks_compile hicks_strabstract
    vespa_compile -> create_gems
    parx_us_par_non_ana_wcm -> vespa_compile
    parx_us_lem_pmc -> vespa_compile
    parx_us_par_ana0 -> vespa_compile
    parx_us_par_ana1 -> vespa_compile
    parx_us_cse -> vespa_compile
    parx_us_cps_hrx_mtx -> vespa_compile
    vespa_rxdx -> parx_us_par_non_ana_wcm parx_us_lem_pmc parx_us_par_ana0 parx_us_par_ana1 parx_us_cse parx_us_cps_hrx_mtx
    vespa_done -> vespa_rxdx
    gif_jkw_stratoplus_compile -> create_gems
    gif_jkw_stratoplus_run -> gif_jkw_stratoplus_compile
    gix_vps_compile -> create_gems
    gix_vps_run -> gix_vps_compile
    mlcp_compile -> geostat_rxdx h2o2pkg_rxdx
    mlcp_run -> mlcp_compile
    ui_hip -> h2o2_rxdx
    ui_lib -> ui_hip
    ui_elab -> ui_lib
    ui_sdc -> ui_elab
    ui_reg -> bios_pre_take_EM2_INITREG
    ui_fsdb_str -> ui_reg
    ui_profile_powers -> ui_sdc
    ui_gui -> ui_profile_powers
    ui_power -> ui_sdc ui_reg
    ui_report -> ui_power
    rxdx_jg_compile -> create_gems
    strnumer -> bios_csv
    h2o2_rxdx -> strnumer bios_csv
    h2o2pkg_rxdx -> geostat_rxdx h2o2_rxdx
    rxdx_sd_apt_compile -> create_gems
    rxdx_sd_apt_sam_autogen -> rxdx_sd_apt_compile
    rxdx_check_lint_error_stage -> rxdx_sd_apt_sam_autogen
    rxdx_sd_apt_run_top -> rxdx_check_lint_error_stage
    natofax_cps_hrx_mtx_sd_apt_sam_autogen -> rxdx_sd_apt_compile
    natofax_cps_hrx_mtx_check_lint_error_stage -> natofax_cps_hrx_mtx_sd_apt_sam_autogen
    natofax_cse_sd_apt_sam_autogen -> rxdx_sd_apt_compile
    natofax_cse_check_lint_error_stage -> natofax_cse_sd_apt_sam_autogen
    natofax_lem_pmc_sd_apt_sam_autogen -> rxdx_sd_apt_compile
    natofax_lem_pmc_check_lint_error_stage -> natofax_lem_pmc_sd_apt_sam_autogen
    natofax_lem_pmc_gui -> natofax_lem_pmc_check_lint_error_stage
    natofax_par_ana0_sd_apt_sam_autogen -> rxdx_sd_apt_compile
    natofax_par_ana0_check_lint_error_stage -> natofax_par_ana0_sd_apt_sam_autogen
    natofax_par_non_ana_wcm_sd_apt_sam_autogen -> rxdx_sd_apt_compile
    natofax_par_non_ana_wcm_check_lint_error_stage -> natofax_par_non_ana_wcm_sd_apt_sam_autogen
    tcd_create_gems -> cors_mangled_pre_ft bios_rxdx_sunforce_rtl bios_rxdx_sunforce_uvm
    pre_sinus -> tcd_create_gems bios_cpp
    tcd_level0 -> pre_sinus
    zenf -> bios_level0_EM1 rxdx_sd_apt_run_top hicks_run_top gif_jkw_stratoplus_run
}

Thanks

Top to bottom is a bad layout direction choice if the labels are wide.  LR is better.  I think making the boxes fixed size and using splines=ortho would help a lot too.  increase ranksep and decrease nodesep.

@Wyck your suggestion does improve the view a bit. I have kept node fontsize as 40 and edge fontsize as 15. Still the node names are coming very small making it difficult to read.

I think to do better your have to cluster your subgraphs

well I did that earlier, it is good but not quite helping. Thanks nevertheless. I am writing this graph.gv from my Python code. Any other idea for better visualization using graphviz or anything is welcome.

use unflatten (https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/unflatten.1.pdf)  on your file before running dot. Try unflatten -fl5

@sroush it helped a bit I must say!
